# How do I have a button and a label share the same width using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

```swift
struct PasswordGenerator : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                //123
                Text("Upon clicking the button the password\nwill also be copied so you\ncan simply paste")
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                Spacer()
                    //123
                    Button(action: generatePassword) {
                        HStack {
                            Image("GeneratorGlyph")
                            Text("Generate!").font(.title)
                            }
                            .accentColor(.white)
                                                .frame(minHeight: 56, maxHeight: 112)
                                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                        }
                        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.init(red: 48/255, green: 153/255, blue: 216/255), Color.init(red: 65/255, green: 165/255, blue: 237/255)]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing), cornerRadius: 9)
                Spacer()
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Generator"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

So I have a button and a Text label (I put a comment that says 123 over both of them so it's easier for you to see) and I was wondering how I could have the button have the same width as the Text label.

Answer (score 0):

Just add padding to your button:

```
.padding(.horizontal, 40)
```